# How to compute the difference in means estimator using `MatchIt` propensity score matching output?

Tags: propensity-scores, matching

From `MatchIt`, we are able to obtain a list of treatment and control pairings. I am wondering how it is possible to find the differences in means estimator from `MatchIt`. It appears that they use `zelig` as a way to estimate the effects, but is there a simple way to find the differences in means estimator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is maybe more of a computing question, but the best way is using the `MatchItSE` package because of its ability to compute the correct standard errors. See the documentation for that package. The help file for the `abadie_imbends_se()` function provides the following example:

```
data("lalonde")
m.out <- matchit(treat ~ educ + black, data = lalonde)
att(obj = m.out, Y = lalonde$re78)
abadie_imbens_se(obj = m.out, Y = lalonde$re78)
```

The second to last step computes that ATT (i.e., the difference in means), and the last step produces the Abadie and Imbens standard errors.

A more straightforward way is to use `matchdata()` on your MatchIt object, which will produce a data set of just you matched units, and you can perform a t-test on them. Also, you can use `lm()` on the full data set and use the weights that are output by `matchit()` in the `weights` argument.